# Temp Table Column Name Sensitivity

Tags: sql-server, collation

I am in a sticky situation. Originally my database catalog is case-insensitive. I write happy queries without minding capitalization of my variable names. Everything was good. After my database is migrated to a different host, the collation at *server instance* level is case sensitive. Now my variable names need spell checked and case checked.

that is alright as I use variables sparingly.

Recently a situation arisen where I need to use temp tables to buffer some results from multiple views before referring them in my main query. In essence:

```
SELECT * INTO #myview1 FROM vw_myview1
SELECT * INTO #myview2 FROM vw_myview2
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM #myview1 v1
JOIN #myview2 v2 on v1.id = v2.id
```

All would be good if my database instance had case insensitive collation. But no. In my main queries, I would have column name capitalization all messed up, WorkID, workId, workid, You name it. I have more than 50 of these queries where I need the temp tables workaround. It's insane and error prone to have to fix the capitalization for every instance that refer to columns in the new temp table . Is there anyways I can flip a switch and say ignore column name collations for this temp table?

Comment: TL;DR nope. In truth, even if you're writing in a case insensitive collation, you should still ensuring that the casing of your objects is correct. If you are using a case sensitive collation now, you either need to change to a case insensitive one (at database level) or fix the queries. There's isn't a "work around", as then the collation wouldn't be working as designed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to insure the temporary table has the column collation you require, there are a couple of ways.  It a is PITA, but not so bad.  For 50+ tables, it's still a PITA.

In SSMS, use the Tools -> Options dialog to get to "SQL Server Object Explorer".  The "Scripting" options are located here.  Set the option for "include collation" to true.  Then script out the table or view.  Convert the script from the table to the temp table syntax you need.

You can also "cheat" and use a new table in the same database rather than a temp table.  It's up to you to clean up. If it's large, it will be in the transaction log.

I've seen examples where the insert into uses a subquery for a column name from the source with a where 1=2.  This causes the collation to be included.  It only creates the table.  It seems funky to me and more tedious than scripting it out.